# Python requests doesn't work but cURL does to PUT file

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, python-requests

I'm having trouble making an api request using python's request lib.

I have tested the endpoint using cURL and it works, but something in my python code makes the api call fail with status 500. My guess is it's something related to how the data/files are structured.
Does anyone see something obviously wrong that I'm failing to see?

I first tried with Postman, which worked, and the cURL command it outputs also works.

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://myurl/endpoint' 
--header 'client-id: my-client-id' 
--header 'client-secret: my-client-secret' 
--header 'correlation-id: my-correlation-id' 
--header 'backend: service' 
--form 'entity_content={"Title":"1megabytetestimage","PathOnClient":"1mbimage.jpg"};type=application/json' 
--form 'VersionData=@"/path/to/1mbimage.jpg"' 
--cert certificate.pem
```

The python code that doesn't work is:

```
import requests

url = 'https://myurl/endpoint'
headers = {
    'client-id': 'my-client-id',
    'client-secret': 'my-client-secret',
    'correlation-id': 'my-correlation-id',
    'backend': 'service',
}

data = {
    'entity_content': '{"Title":"1megabytetestimage","PathOnClient":"1mbimage.jpg"};type=application/json'
}


files = {
    'VersionData': ('1mbimage.jpg', open('/mnt/d/1mbimage.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg'),
}

response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, files=files, data=data, cert='certificate.pem')
```

I've tried a large amount if iterations with small changes here and there and nothing seems to work.
Unfortunately I cannot provide the actual url, client-id and secret.

Edit:

The response I get is:

```
--ec2f2bf4ebd9869d1d6a6a2d7f3b1ab7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content"

{"Title":"1megabytetestimage","PathOnClient":"1mbimage.jpg"};type=application/json
--ec2f2bf4ebd9869d1d6a6a2d7f3b1ab7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="1mbimage.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<Image Bytes>
--ec2f2bf4ebd9869d1d6a6a2d7f3b1ab7--
```

Image Bytes seems to be the whole image file in bytes format, which is unreadable.

Comment: Hi, could you try change `files` to an array, like they show in the [documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files)? Also, does the Python code produce any error message? If yes, you could add it into your question.

Comment: Have you tried without the ";type=application/json" part in the value-part of the `data` dict? I think requests takes care of handling that.

Comment: @marek I have indeed tried that and I still get status 500.

Comment: @9769953 I also tried that to no avail.

Comment: Just to check: could you try with the `--http1.1` option added to the cURL command, and see if that still works correctly?

Comment: @9769953 It does still work with that option

Comment: @Diogo Vala HTTP Status 500 is [Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/status/500), which might mean anything (any type of errors or the server is just hiding some information from the users). Double check that you are sending data that fits their schema. If it doesn't help, consider contacting people in charge of the server. They might have more insights into the inner working of this server.